# Does the parameter with 0-coefficient in lasso regression never goes back to non-zero as the penalization increasing($\lambda$ increasing)? Why?

Tags: regression, lasso

Just as the problem, when I draw the lasso path along with $\lambda$ increasing:

\begin{equation}
L(\lambda) = f(x; \beta) - \lambda||\beta||
\end{equation}

I found any coefficient, for instance, $\beta_j$. If $\hat \beta_j$ shrinks to 0, then it just sticks to 0 and never become non-zero value anymore when I increase the penalization(tuning parameter) $\lambda$: 
[image]

Is this phenomenon always true? Or just coincidence? I'm seeking for the answer as this property may bring quite lot of convenience during numerical calculation.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: your $w_4$ seems to go non-zero when it was zero around $\lambda\approx2.5$; and in the loss function, you should add the regularization term instead of subtracting it.